# Is there a software tool / wizard to dual install ubuntu onto a pc with windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot

I've been using Ubuntu on a laptop which is now dead. I have a shiny new one which came with windows 8. I would like to put Ubuntu on it for dual boot. Ive been reading extensively about this, but what's worrying is the list of user comments after each article saying "Ok, I did all that and now something's gone horribly wrong..!".
I had a look at WUBI but it seems that's out of date and about to disappear completely.

Is there / anyone making some GUI based software for computer illiterate dorks like me to dual-install Ubuntu nicely and easily, accounting for all the UEFI, Secure Boot, Compatibility mode, Grubs etc problems that seem to be stacked high under every forum I read? (And put the fear into me).  Or, of course, point me in the direction of a fool-proof guide which works every time!

Thanks!

Comment: what are the partitions on your device? I'm guessing just one for Windows, right?

Answer (score 0):

No there are no such tool.

Need a worry free dual boot setup?

1. Create restoration disk if your laptop guide said so, or you must have the windows 8 install media. Take backup of any important data that you have left in this laptop.
2. Use [Advanced Token Manager](http://joshcellsoftwares.com/products/advancedtokensmanager/) to take a backup of windows 8 activation data, just in case.
3. Open BIOS, Disable `secure boot` and change boot type from `uefi` to `legacy`. [Can't really help here as different manufacturer put them in different menu.]
4. Reinstall windows 8 (do the necessary stuff activation, driver installation etc), and then install ubuntu with ease.

If not ready for the above, and want new features of UEFI (I don't know what they provide)
Follow -

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Also look at - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Remember to use 64bit images. 32bit images won't detect UEFI.